# ¿Por qué falla la substitución de este argumento de plantilla?

Tags: c++, template, sfinae

Dispongo de unas funciones plantilla que recibiendo un índice (en el ejemplo es un `int`) devuelven un valor del tipo solicitado, he usado FASNEUE ([SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)) para separar los casos especiales:

```
// 1
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type
t(int) { ... }

// 2
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<std::string, T>::value, T>::type
t(int) { ... }

// 3
template <template <typename ...> class T, typename ... P>
T<P ...> t(int) { ... }
```

Adicionalmente, una función que recibe un contenedor y lo rellena usando las funciones anteriores:

```
template <typename C>
C c(int)
{
    C r{};
    std::insert_iterator<C> iterator(r, r.begin());
    *iterator = t<typename C::value_type>(0);
    return r;
}
```

Cuando se deserializan contenedores no asociativos, el código se comporta de la manera esperada pero al deserializar contenedores asociativos el código no compila:

```
using vi = std::vector<int>;
using mii = std::map<int, int>;

auto o = c<vi>(0);  // Deserializar vector
auto p = c<mii>(0); // Deserializar mapa
```

El problema está en la llamada a deserializar un elemento del contenedor:

```
*iterator = t<typename C::value_type>(0);
```

En el caso de contenedores no asociativos `C::value_type` es un tipo que entra por cualquiera de las dos primeras versiones de la función `t`. En el caso de un contenedor asociativo `C::value_type` es un par, que debería fallar al intentar instanciar las dos primeras versiones de `t` y no fallar al instanciar la tercera; sin embargo falla en los tres casos:

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to 't'
> *iterator = t<typename C::value_type>(0);
>             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'c<std::map<int, int>>' requested here
> auto p = c<mii>(0);
>          ^
> note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'std::is_arithmetic<pair<const int, int> >::value' was not satisfied [with T = std::pair<const int, int>]
> t(int) { ... }
> ^
> note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'std::is_same<std::string, pair<const int, int> >::value' was not satisfied [with T = std::pair<const int, int>]
> t(int) { ... }
> ^
> note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'T'
> T<P ...> t(int) { ... }
>          ^
> ```

Parece que se está quejando de la falta de parámetros plantilla en la plantilla-plantilla de la tercera versión de la función `t`, pero si dejo de usar FASNEUE el fallo desaparece:

```
template <typename T>
T
t(int) { return {}; }

template <template <typename ...> class T, typename ... P>
T<P ...> t(int) { return {}; }

template <typename C>
C c(int)
{
    C r{};
    std::insert_iterator<C> iterator(r, r.begin());
    *iterator = t<typename C::value_type>(0);
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    using vi = std::vector<int>;
    using mii = std::map<int, int>;

    auto o = c<vi>(0);
    auto p = c<mii>(0);

    // muestra 0
    for (auto &v : o) std::cout << v << '\n';
    // muestra 00
    for (auto &v : p) std::cout << v.first << v.second << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Así que aparentemente FASNEUE está haciendo que en la plantilla-plantilla el parámetro plantilla-plantilla pase a ser requerido ¿Por qué pasa esto? ¿Cómo solucionarlo?

Puede consultarse un ejemplo del problema en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Dj96G6V15bBT2c3S)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFINAE no es la solución al problema porque para que funcione correctamente se deben deshabilitar **todas** las sobrecargas menos una... y en el caso que presentas hay al menos dos sobrecargas de la función (la específica del tipo y la variádica).

En esta situación el compilador entenderá que estás intentando especializar la plantilla... pero la sintaxis no concuerda con la de una especialización y el compilador se queja.

Una posible solución podría pasar por realizar especializaciones del compilador:

```
// Implementacion por defecto no valida
template<class T>
T t(int); 

template<>
int t<int>(int)
{ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; return 0; }

template<>
std::string t<std::string>(int)
{ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; return ""; }

template<typename First, typename Second>
typename std::pair<First,Second> t<typename std::pair<First,Second>>(int)
{ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; return std::make_pair(First{},Second{}); }
```

Pero claro la última función acaba siendo una especialización parcial y eso al compilador no le gusta (es parcial porque `std::pair` depende de los tipos `First` y `Second`... cosas de los compiladores).

Esta situación la podemos solventar especializando clases en vez de funciones:

```
template<class T>
struct t;

template<>
struct t<int>
{
  static int Func(int)
  { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; return 0; }
};

template<>
struct t<std::string>
{
  static std::string Func(int)
  { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; return ""; }
};

template<typename First, typename Second>
struct t<std::pair<First,Second>>
{
  static std::pair<First,Second> Func(int)
  { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; return std::make_pair(First{},Second{}); }
};
```

Ahora modificamos ligeramente la implementación de la función de enlace:

```
template <typename C>
C c(int)
{
    C r{};
    std::insert_iterator<C> iterator(r, r.begin());
    *iterator = t<typename C::value_type>::Func(0);
    //                                   ^^^^^^ AQUI!!!
    return r;
}
```

Y listo... el código ya funciona ([ejemplo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/E2ArHOPRXeVtcB2T)).

Aun así, lidiar con mapas y contenedores complejos no es buena idea ya que los posibles casos de uso se multiplican y eso no es sencillo de gestionar ni siquiera con plantillas.